# Calendar name change via ui not triggering webhook notification on CalendarList endpoint

Tags: google-calendar-api

We are receiving notifications when calendars are added and removed, even when the color is merely toggled via web browser, but when the name of the calendar is changed, nothing.

Comment: I think that you don't just change the name of the calendar as it's linked to the calendar when you [made watch requests](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#making-watch-requests). Try making a separate watch request for that other calendar.

Comment: Are you saying that a new calendar is created with a simple name change???  Somehow I can't fathom that.